# Website publishing help needed

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have written a code in HTML for my first website. The code is written in Notepad. I would like to know how to publish it & what is the help of DREAMWAVER. 
Is DREAMWAVER required to upload the coding on web hosting services or it can be uploaded directly?If yes, how?

Thank You...

Comment: To view what you have created in notepad, you could go to `save as` then add `.html` at the end of you file name and it will save it as html file so you can see how it would look in a browser.

Comment: No, Dreamweaver is not required. Nobody needs Dreamweaver for anything. You need a *website host*, which you pay some money. They in turn will give you instructions where and how to upload stuff.

Comment: I hope at least you mean notepad++ instead of notepad

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+upload+a+website -- not sure which one of those to link to, so I'm just sharing my Google search with you.

Comment: You can host small, static (html) sites out of google drive (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en). Cant recommend this as a long term solution but it might serve the purpose of learning and getting the site up so that you can test and tweak it before having to pay for hosting space.

Comment: You might also want to consider GitHub pages: https://pages.github.com/, which is free, and you learn about how to properly manage code, with version control.

Answer (score 2):

In order to upload your files to a remote host, you need to:

- have such a host ready (purchase a hosting account, perhaps find a free one if one is available)
- use software capable of connecting to your remote host and transferring files over a file transfer protocol of some sort (FTP, SFTP, FTPS, SCP - depends on what your remote host makes available to you).

The connection details such as the hostname, port, username and password should be provided by the hosting company as soon as you purchase your hosting plan.

The software capable of making an FTP connection includes FileZilla along with many others, frequently platform-dependent applications. You can also use an IDE. I assume Dreamweaver is capable of file upload to a server. Same holds for Aptana, NetBeans, JetBrains WebStorm (or PhpStorm or IntelliJ or...) and many others. You need to establish a connection and transfer the files you created to a directory known as the docroot - usually it's called "public", "public_html", sometimes "web" or "htdocs" - this varies and you should make sure your files end up in the right place.

After the files are in place, they should be accessible through the browser (this is usually true of shared hosts at least, where a suitable vhost configuration is created for you; I assume you don't want a private server you manage yourself, so I'll not get into detail here).

Answer (score 1):

1. Get web space. Wether it's a paid service or free web space it's up to you.
2. Write HTML code. Use an HTML Editor for this (there are free editors out there), not Notepad. It makes your life a whole lot easier.
3. Publish your files to the webspace. Almost all web spaces grant you FTP access, so get an FTP client like FileZilla (it's free).
4. ???
5. Profit!